Has anyone figured out how to connect to tuya MQTT standard protocol on an esp32?
I'm trying to connect to the Tuya IoT Developer platform using https://developer.tuya.com/en/docs/iot/MQTT-protocol?id=Kb65nphxrj8f1 as a reference.
I've created a product in the developer portal already but can't seem to get my esp32 to connect to the Tuya MQTT servers.
Here's what I've written
#include <Seeed_mbedtls.h>

#define KEY_SIZE 32  // 256 bits for HMAC-SHA256
#define OUTPUT_SIZE 32 // SHA-256 outputs 32 bytes

// Your 256-bit secret key (32 bytes)
String str = "DeviceSecret";
const uint8_t* deviceSecret = (const uint8_t*)str.c_str();

#include <WiFi.h>
WiFiClient wifiClient;

#include <time.h>     // include time library

// (utc+) TZ in hours

long timezone = 0; 

byte daysavetime = 0;

#include <PubSubClient.h>
PubSubClient client(wifiClient);

// Set up wifi
#define SSID "SSID"
#define WIFI_PWD "pwd"


// MQTT set up

//MQTT server
#define MQTT_BROKER "m1.tuyacn.com"
#define MQTT_PORT (8883)


String compute_hmac_sha256(const uint8_t *key, size_t key_len, const uint8_t *input, size_t input_len) {
    mbedtls_md_context_t ctx;
    const mbedtls_md_info_t *md_info;
    uint8_t hmac_output[32]; // SHA-256 outputs 32 bytes

    mbedtls_md_init(&ctx);
    md_info = mbedtls_md_info_from_type(MBEDTLS_MD_SHA256);

    if (md_info == NULL) {
        Serial.println("Failed to get MD info for SHA256");
        mbedtls_md_free(&ctx);
        return String();
    }

    if (mbedtls_md_setup(&ctx, md_info, 1) != 0) {
        Serial.println("Failed to setup MD context");
        mbedtls_md_free(&ctx);
        return String();
    }

    if (mbedtls_md_hmac_starts(&ctx, key, key_len) != 0) {
        Serial.println("Failed to start HMAC");
        mbedtls_md_free(&ctx);
        return String();
    }

    if (mbedtls_md_hmac_update(&ctx, input, input_len) != 0) {
        Serial.println("Failed to update HMAC");
        mbedtls_md_free(&ctx);
        return String();
    }

    if (mbedtls_md_hmac_finish(&ctx, hmac_output) != 0) {
        Serial.println("Failed to finish HMAC");
        mbedtls_md_free(&ctx);
        return String();
    }

    mbedtls_md_free(&ctx);

    // Convert the HMAC output to a hexadecimal string
    String hmac_str;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(hmac_output); i++) {
        char buf[3];
        sprintf(buf, "%02x", hmac_output[i]);
        hmac_str += buf;
    }

    return hmac_str;
}

// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.print("Connecting to " SSID);
  WiFi.begin(SSID, WIFI_PWD); // attempt to connect to an existing wifi
  //Wait for wifi to connect
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(" . ");
    }
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  //Time Server Set up
  Serial.println("Contacting Time Server");
  configTime(3600*timezone, daysavetime*3600, "time.nist.gov", "0.pool.ntp.org", "1.pool.ntp.org");
  delay(1000);

  time_t now;
  time(&now); 

  //MQTT Credentials set up
  String MQTT_USERNAME = "deviceID|signMethod=hmacSha256,timestamp=" + String(now) +",secureMode=1,accessType=1";

      // Your original const char* message
    const char *message = "deviceId=deviceID,timestamp=,secureMode=1,accessType=1";

    // The String you want to insert
    String additional = String(now);

    // Convert the original message to a String
    String messageString = String(message);

    // Insert the additional String at the 43rd position
    size_t insertPos = 42; // Position to insert
    messageString = messageString.substring(0, insertPos) + additional + messageString.substring(insertPos);


    // Convert the modified message back to const char*
    const char* final_message = messageString.c_str();



  // Compute HMAC-SHA256
  String MQTT_PWD = compute_hmac_sha256(deviceSecret, KEY_SIZE, (const uint8_t *)final_message, strlen(final_message));
  Serial.println(now);

  Serial.print("MQTT_PWD: ");
  Serial.println(MQTT_PWD);

 Serial.println("init successfull");
 String tuyalink = "tuyalink_DeviceId";
    // Handle MQTT connection.
  client.setServer(MQTT_BROKER, MQTT_PORT); // set broker settings
  while (! client.connected()) { // check connected status
    if ( client.connect(tuyalink.c_str(),MQTT_USERNAME.c_str(),MQTT_PWD.c_str())){ // connect with random id
      Serial.println("MQTT connected."); // report success
      //client.subscribe("Test/ra542");
    } else {
      Serial. printf (" failed , rc=%d try again in 5 seconds", client.state ()); // report error
      delay(5000); // wait 5 seconds
    }
  }



}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
Serial.println("Hello World!");
delay(5000);

            
}

In my final code I've replaced the deviceId and DeviceSecret with the credentials I've gotten from tuya
On Connecting to the MQTT Server I get
failed , rc=-4 try again in 5 seconds failed

According to https://pubsubclient.knolleary.net/api#state rc -4 means the server didn't respond within the keepalive time.
I've tried increasing the keep alive time to 60s but that doesn't change anything
  uint16_t keepAlive = 60000;
  client.setKeepAlive(keepAlive);

When Testing with test.mosquitto.org and port 1883 without credentials it seems to work fine.
I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here. Any ideas/pointers would be greatly appreciated


configTime(3600timezone, daysavetime3600, "time.nist.gov", "0.pool.ntp.org", "1.pool.ntp.org");
delay(1000);

The access to an NTP server with configTime() take time, it could varies from a few ms to a minute. So the delay(1000) isn't adequate, and if it failed, the rest of the code of trying to insert the timestamp would insert the incorrect data.
Here is a suggestion for ensuring the configTime get the correct timestamp.
  int timeOut = 0;
  configTime(3600*timezone, daysavetime*3600, "time.nist.gov", "0.pool.ntp.org", "1.pool.ntp.org");
  while (time(nullptr) < 1716086610) { // 1716086610 is just a valid timestamp in recent past
      delay(1000);
  };

  time_t now = time(NULL);


Update
Further to your comment, if you are using PORT 8883, you probably need a secure TCP connection. I don't have tuya account, but I test the following code on test.mosquitto.org:port 8883 with the following code that you might want to adopt it for your application.
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <time.h>

// Set up wifi
#define SSID "wifi_ssid"
#define WIFI_PWD "wifi_password"

// MQTT set up
#define MQTT_BROKER "test.mosquitto.org"
#define MQTT_PORT 8883

WiFiClientSecure wifiClient;
PubSubClient client(wifiClient);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.print("Connecting to WiFi");
  WiFi.begin(SSID, WIFI_PWD);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");

  //Time Server Set up
  Serial.println("Contacting Time Server");
  configTime(3600*timezone, daysavetime*3600, "time.nist.gov", "0.pool.ntp.org", "1.pool.ntp.org");
  while (time(nullptr) < 1716086610) { // 1716086610 is just a valid timestamp in recent past
      delay(1000);
  };

  time_t now = time(NULL);
  
  Serial.println("Contacting to MQTT broker");
  wifiClient.setInsecure(); // not to validate server certificate
  client.setServer(MQTT_BROKER, MQTT_PORT); // set broker settings
  while (! client.connected()) { // check connected status
    if (client.connect("my_mqtt_client") {
      Serial.println("MQTT connected."); // report success
    } else {
      Serial. printf (" failed , rc=%d try again in 5 seconds", client.state ()); // report error
      delay(5000); // wait 5 seconds
    }
  }

}


Thanks for this, I've implemented this version of getting the timestamp but still no luck. Whilst testing delay(1000); has worked but this is a much better way of handling the time retrieval as it allows for much more latency than 1 second.

I forgot to tell you that If you are using port 8883, you probably need to establish a secure TCP connection using WiFiClientSecure. See my update above.

I appreciate the follow up I tested this out and seem to be getting somewhere, using WiFiClientSecure and  wifiClient.setInsecure();. I managed to get it working on the test.mosquitto.org server like you did.
However when I try this with m1.tuyacn.com I get mqtt client state 5
5 : MQTT_CONNECT_UNAUTHORIZED - the client was not authorized to connect
I wasn't able to test this out much today but I suspect it might have to do with the Tuya Iot platform itself.
thanks once again for your help with this.

Tuya cloud need extra authentication such as username and password. Only you can test it, so you need to do some adaptation of the code and debugging yourself.

You must connect to the Tuya server in a secure connection
According to Tuya documentation insert link description here

#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>


WiFiClientSecure wifiClient;

And add the root certificate before connecting to the server

wifiClient.setCACert(Tuya_CERT_CA);

